# Класс многочлен ещё один вопрос

Tags: c#

Многочлен вида (5x^9 + 3x^3 -3) + (3x^4 - 4x^2). Я пробовал реализовать этот класс как словарь, ключ (^9) значение (5) из примера выше. Но, к сожалению, не могу придумать как реализовать сложение и вычитание в такой реализации (так как только учусь). Не могли бы вы подсказать как это можно сделать? Или так не получится ? Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Класс многочлена лучше всего реализовать через массив его коэффициентов (именно в учебных целях), не нужно хранить степени. То есть первый многочлен будет как массив (от младших степеней): `{-3,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,5}` и второй `{0,0,-4,0,3}`. Соответственно, сложить очень просто: складываем соответствующие числа: `{-3,0,-4,3,3,0,0,0,0,5}`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, то есть, если степень многочлена будет 100 и иметь только 5 коофициентов, то этот  массив будет содержать 95 нулей? Просто как-то не очень хорошо будет выглядеть.

Comment: Да, будет именно так нехорошо выглядеть, однако давайте подумаем, вот у вас задание, обычное учебное. Что именно вы тренируете? Если навык создания классов - то вообще не важно что там внутри и как выглядит. Если навык работы со ложными структурами хранения полиномов - другое дело. Далее, если взять общий случай работы с полиномами, то на практике как раз часто возникают ситуации, когда нулей вообще нет, то есть все степени заняты. Хотя это сильно зависит от специфики задачи.

Comment: Спасибо, просто видел миллион решений, на списках и массивах, и хотел сделать по другому. На словарях как-то нагляднее, и как я понял на много сложнее реализовать действия над многочленами. В любом случае благодарю.